# Return the number of times hi appears

Tags: java, string

I'm doing some coding bat exercises and I don't quite understand what's going on inside the for-loop.

```
    public static int countHi(String str){
    int count = 0;

    // While i is less than the length of string increase the index by one
    // Checking the char at each index
    for(int i = 0; i < str.length()-1; i++){
        // Do i + 2 because hi has two letters
        // i = index 0 and add 2 so 0,1,2-- but 2 is exlcuded so check to see if index 0,1 equals "hi"
        if(str.substring(i, i+2).equals("hi")){
            count++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Hi appears: " + count + " times.");
    return count;
}
```

Why is it str.length()-1? If I changed that to just str.Length I get an error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 5

Comment: Is it because the index of the characters starts at 0, so there is an off by one  difference in the total index and the length of the string?

Comment: Because you are doing `if(str.substring(i, i+2)` so if `i` was equal to `one` less that the length and adding `two` would exceed it.

Comment: @Construct0r No, it's because of the (n+2) part. The use of `<` accounts for the index offset.

Comment: @AndrewLi That's not right. You want `-1` for this.

Comment: You have to loop until `8`. `str.substring(8, 10)` is valid because the second substring index is exclusive not inclusive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about this part:

```
str.substring(i, i+2)
```

When `i` is equal to the length of the string, `i + 2` will overshoot the end of the string by 1, giving you an out of bounds error.

Comment: So by making it length() - 1 and when I add 2, because in substring the 2 is exclusive I'm not going out of bounds right?

Comment: @Construct0r Correct. Whenever you're doing "index math", you need to be cautious that the index you produced actually points to an element in the sequence.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you have used i+2 in str.substring(i, i+2), which causes the out of bound exception.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `str.length()` it gives you the length of the string, while the max index of string that is accessible is given by `str.length() - 1`. For example, `"String"` will have length of 6. So, when you try to do this `str.substring(5 , (5+ 2))` it will try to access the index which is out of the bound and hence it throw the exception.